# Does glab (glab-cli) support creating project access tokens?

Tags: gitlab, glab

I would like to make a chore commit in my CI. Currently, [`CI_JOB_TOKEN` doesn't allow pushing to the repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/389060). The workaround is to create a project access token with write perms. Is it possible to do this with `glab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not current, there are two issues opened on this

- [Create Project Access Tokens (PATs) from `glab`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/issues/980)
- [Rotate Project Access Tokens (PATs) from `glab`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cli/-/issues/7435)

And, [this issue will provide a better workaround through prepopulating UI variables](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ui/-/issues/2553)