# How can I push to a repo when CI_JOB_TOKEN doesn't permit it?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Currently, [`CI_JOB_TOKEN` doesn't allow you to push to a repo](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/389060). When I try I get,

> remote: You are not allowed to upload code.

How can I work around this if I need to push to the repo in the CI?

The `CI_REPOSITORY_URL` which has the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` can not be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to do this is to generate a Project Access Token and store it as a protected environmental variable. You can do this like this,

- From the project page, add `/-/settings/access_tokens` to the end of the URL
- You need to create a token with

  - At least the role of `Developer` or greater ([**the default of Guest will NOT work**](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/407725))
  - Add to the token a scope of `write_repository`

Now you need to set this this token up in the project,

- With the `glab` tool use a command like this

  ```
  glab variable set --protected REPO_WRITE_TOKEN myToken
  ```
- With the UI

  - From the project page, add `/-/settings/ci_cd` to the end of the URL
  - Under Variables click Expand
  - Click "Add Variable"

Now all of your jobs have access to `REPO_WRITE_TOKEN` and can push up using,

```
git remote add merge_request "https://does_not_mattter:${REPO_WRITE_TOKEN}@${CI_SERVER_HOST}/${CI_PROJECT_PATH}.git"
```

---

Unfortunately, the [Project Access Token UI page can't be pre-populated yet with query parameters and you can't currently make a Project Access Token from `glab` (the GitLab CLI tool)](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/19061/18965)

Comment: Shouldn't `SSH_REPO_KEY` be `REPO_WRITE_TOKEN` in the remote URL?

Comment: @AlexV keen eye, and yes. That was a mistake on my part. =) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for long read...
You could try that solution:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/authenticate_registry.html#option-3-use-docker_auth_config.

That authentication approach can be defined in several ways:

> - In pre_build_script in the runner configuration file.
> - In before_script.
> - In script.

1. Set DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG CI\CD variable on project\group\instance level (don't forget to check Expand option).
   Once you have DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG set up correctly, Docker commands like docker push or docker pull in your GitLab CI/CD pipeline will be able to authenticate with the registry automatically.
2. Set variables REGISTRY_PULL_AUTH_BASE64 and REGISTRY_URL. REGISTRY_PULL_AUTH_BASE64 should contain base64 encoded login:password. Or use direct values registry.example.com and encoded login:password.

```
echo -n 'login:password' | base64
bG9naW46cGFzc3dvcmQ=
```

DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG with nested variables.

```
{
    "auths": {
        "$REGISTRY_URL": {
            "auth": "$REGISTRY_PULL_AUTH_BASE64"
        },
        "$REGISTRY_URL": {
            "auth": "$REGISTRY_PUSH_AUTH_BASE64"
        }
    }
}
```

That's it. During pipeline execution variable will authenticate in docker automatically.

.gitlab-ci.yml example before_script and script blocks:

```
before_script:
  - docker info

build:
  script:
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
```